# AS3, basic OOP, I guess?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

OK I've got some question about what I guess is basic OOP. For example, let's say I have many diffrent objects which has diffrent classes. Let's say, one object called, car (Car.as), then I have a truck (truck.as) and a moped (moped.as). Now instead of writing a simple function within all of these, can't I have a class and then attach this function onto everyone of these objects?

For example I want them to be able to fade out. Then I have a class called "AlphaThings" and within this class I write a simple fadeout function.

Can't I somehow then attach this function to another object? Like

```
AlphaThings.fadeout(car);
AlphaThings.fadeout(truck);
AlphaThings.fadein(moped);
```

Thanks, and sorry if there some misspelled words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to accomplish inheritance, which is where a class inherits properties and methods from another.

Inheritance is accomplished by using the `extends` keyword when defining the class.

Your three objects `Car`, `Truck` and `Moped` could inherit from (extend) `AlphaThings` like this:

```
class Car extends AlphaThings
{
    //
}
```

Your `Car` will now contain all of the properties and methods defined within `AlphaThings`, such as `.fadein()` and `.fadeout()` that you mentioned.

**Bonus info**:

When you extend another class, you can alter how methods existing within the base class will work in the class inheriting from it. This is done using the `override` keyword.

For example, you may want your `Car` to do something slightly different or additional when you use `.fadein()` on it, so you would override that method like this:

```
override public function fadein():void
{
    // Some additional logic.
    // ...

    super.fadein();
}
```

The line `super.fadein()` is there to call the original `.fadein()` function. If you omit this, you can completely rewrite the function and have the previously defined actions ignored.

**Regarding this specific scenario**:

This answer of course gets straight to the point and answers the question directly by explaining how to achieve *inheritance*. With that said, what you're trying to achieve can be done more cleanly using one of a handful of other routes.

For example, consider this [Tweening Library by Greensock](https://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/). The library can deal with the transitioning of any values (including alpha) on any objects in different ways. Here are some examples of why this is great vs using inheritance:

1. The library is completely separate from your actual objects.
2. The library can be made as powerful as you like without making all of your other game objects heavier than they need to be. You'll notice for example that there are many types of transition styles you can use (e.g. ease out, ease in, etc) - imagine if all of that was part of your base object.
3. You can target anything with the library, meaning that you do not need to extend `AlphaThings` from your example to use it.
4. It is relatively easy to detach or swap out with another library if you decide down the track that it it no longer necessary or you've found something better.
5. You can re-use the library easily across your projects, versus having to extract bits and pieces of code from `AlphaThings` in a new project.

Comment: @user1133188 No worries, added some extra info which you will find useful in the near future.

Comment: In this particular case, why would inheritance solve things better? Why not have a Fader class and use composition instead of inheritance? Or even the static method solution OP gave as an example? All you're going to accomplish here is a more complex structure, with more lines of code and tight coupling.... there is nothing better than in the original version! Inheritance is a powerful tool, but only if you use it wisely.

Comment: Well, you're welcome to explain the other solution aswell, I'm still new to AS3, and all new information is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You would declare the behavior you want in a parent class, then derive Car, Truck and Moped from that.  They'll then get the methods.

The following link explains it in more detail:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html